# ANR on Live WallPaper OplusWallpaperServiceExt.finishDrawing when set WallPaper

Tags: service, crash, live-wallpaper, android-anr-dialog, oppo

I am Facing Issue on OPPO devices Android version 12 and  For two weeks I have tried to resolve this issue but can't resolve it, Any One Know the solution Kindly suggest me.

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException:
  at android.service.wallpaper.OplusWallpaperServiceExt.finishDrawing (OplusWallpaperServiceExt.java:134)
  at android.service.wallpaper.OplusWallpaperServiceExt.reportFinishDrawing (OplusWallpaperServiceExt.java:96)
  at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.updateSurface (WallpaperService.java:1267)
  at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$Engine.attach (WallpaperService.java:1356)
  at android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService$IWallpaperEngineWrapper.executeMessage (WallpaperService.java:2230)
  at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage (HandlerCaller.java:44)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:233)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:344)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8205)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:589)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1071)
```

Trace this Service class, Check out Wallpaper Service class test on every OPPO device but can't even trace the crash ,browsing the solution and find nothing. Expecting a proper way to trace it and fix this issue.